# Augeas edit option if it exist, add otherwise - while referencing newly created node

Tags: puppet, nfs, augeas

I want to do something along the lines of:

```
set /files/etc/exports/dir[. = '/export/home'][client = '10.0.0.0/8'] /export/home
set /files/etc/exports/dir[. = '/export/home'][client = '10.0.0.0/8']/client 10.0.0.0/8
```

What happens if I run the above is that the second command creates yet another new node, without any dir value set. My challenge is that /export/home share is not a unique dir, as clients are added on new lines for readability. I need both dir and client search options to find a unique node.

How can I reference the (maybe) newly created node in command 1, such that the end result is:

```
/export/home 10.0.0.0/8()
```

Answer (score 1):

Augeas have something called [defnode](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/wiki/Adding-nodes-to-the-tree#append-and-store-in-a-variable) which do a set command and store the resulting node in the variable specified.

Solution to my problem:

```
defnode newdir /files/etc/exports/dir[. = '/export/home' and client = '10.0.0.0/8'] /export/home
set $newdir/client 10.0.0.0/8
set $newdir/client/option[1] rw
set $newdir/client/option[2] async
set $newdir/client/option[3] no_subtree_check
```

***Edit**: Changed `][` to `and` for better readability

Comment: That is indeed the best option. As a note, it is better to use `[a and b]` than `[a][b]`.

Comment: It's not only a matter of readability, it's a different logic. `[a][b]` selects first the nodeset that matches `[a]`, and then selects another sub-nodeset from it that matches `[b]`; while `[a and b]` only does one matching, on the `[a and b]` condition.